BUG:A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in NumPy 2.0.0 as it may crash
today I encountered this problem while working on my Python project, even though I wasn't directly using numpy:
A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in
NumPy 2.0.0 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x
versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0.
Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12'.

If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.

and then:
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 2
      1 audio = audio.set_frame_rate(params.sample_rate)
----> 2 spectrogram = converter.spectrogram_from_audio(audio)
      4 plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
      5 plt.imshow(librosa.power_to_db(spectrogram.squeeze()), origin='lower', aspect='auto', interpolation="nearest")

File c:\Users\ACER\OneDrive\Desktop\MLproject\utils.py:254, in SpectrogramConverter.spectrogram_from_audio(self, audio)
    251 if waveform.dtype != np.float32:
    252     waveform = waveform.astype(np.float32)
--> 254 waveform_tensor = torch.from_numpy(waveform).to(self.device)
    255 amplitudes_mel = self.mel_amplitudes_from_waveform(waveform_tensor)
    256 return amplitudes_mel.cpu().numpy()

RuntimeError: Numpy is not available

I have already tried downgrading the numpy version and restarting the kernel, but nothing seems to resolve the issue at the moment. The problem seems to come when I import "utils" that is a file of the same folder where I have some useful functions.

you don't have to use numpy directly because it is very popular and it can be used by torch to keep all data. And it may need to dowgrade not only numpy but also torch, etc.
